# Html Formatted String to Textview

Tags: android, html, kotlin, formatting

So I tried the technique of putting the Html string inside triple quotes, as given here:

[How can I display formatted text in a TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46008925/how-can-i-display-formatted-text-in-a-textview/46009430#46009430)

(In Kotlin), as follows:

```
    val x = """Test {
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x7fb6dec147b0> font-family: \"Roboto\"; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 18.00pt";
}We are 'testing the waters'"""
    

    val sp = Html.fromHtml(x,1)
    helpTextView.setText(sp)
```

and No formatting results in my textview, it comes out literally like you see it inside the triple quotes.

What is wrong? How can I get this out properly formatted?

Mod: I put this in as a separate Question cuz that's the only way I could post.

Comment: That does not appear to be valid HTML.

Comment: Thank you guys, I have found that the code I posted contained control directives for Xcode the iOS development environment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where triple quotes are in the link you posted, but they are not necessary.

You need this

`HtmlCompat.fromHtml("<b>Hello<b/>", HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)`

(Inside the quotes put the HTML you want

Answer (score 0):

Again see my comment above, using proper HTML directives and the technique supplied by Lenin I’m well on my way. Thank you guys